# httpd: How to redirect all calls to one directory to another directory?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to execute some PHP code that references code in `/this/is/my/path/public` but this directory does not exist. The actual directory is `/this/is/my/path/htdocs` so when I try to run this code, I get this error:

```
Warning: opendir(/this/is/my/path/public/assets/js/build-plugins/): failed to open dir: No such file or directory
```

I was hoping to use `.htaccess`, or something similar, to redirect calls from one directory to another. I have tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ /htdocs/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

and this:

```
RewriteRule ^public/(.+)$ /this/is/my/path/htdocs/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

but to no avail. Maybe I'm approaching this in the wrong way and a symbolic link would be better?

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your PHP code on how are you accessing code in `/this/is/my/path/public`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symlinks is a good solution, also you can try Alias apache directive

Alias /public /path/htdocs